# Как сделать всплывающее окно в Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Как сделать такое окно, которое при нажатии на кнопку будет выводится на экран, а при нажатии на любую другую часть экрана закрывалось?

[image]

Comment: Это называется `dialog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вам выше ответили - эта штука называется dialog.

Вот самый простой пример создания оного и обработки кликов по кнопкам:

```
public void сreateDialog(Activity activity) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setTitle("Диалог")
            .setMessage("Текст в диалоге")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Нажата кнопка 'OK'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Нажата кнопка 'Отмена'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}
```